# I want to tell the user that they are very lucky if they get heard or tail 6 times in a row

Tags: python, coin-flipping

I am trying to create a Coin Flip Game this is what I have came up with so far:

```
import random

def headsOrTails(number_of_flips):
  number_of_flips = int(input("How many times do you want to flip the coin: "))
  heards_count = 0
  tails_count = 0
  for i in range(number_of_flips):
    rand = random.randint(1, 2)
    if rand == 1:
      heards_count += 1
      print(f"It is Heads.\n Heads {heards_count}")
    elif rand == 2:
      tails_count += 1
      print(f"It is Tails.\n Tails {tails_count}")
  print(heards_count)
  print(tails_count)
headsOrTails(1)
```

I want to tell the user that they are very lucky if they get heard or tail 6 times in a role. And I was wondering if anyone can help me do that.

Comment: What is `rand == 1 and rand == 1 and rand == 1 and rand == 1` supposed to mean?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]. I don't really understand what part you need help with. What does your current code do? What should it do? Why are you calling it with `number_of_flips=1` instead of `>=6`?

Comment: If you want N in a row, then you need to set `head_count` to 0 when you get tails, and you need to set `tails_count` to 0 when you get heads.  Then, you can print the lucky line when either number equals 6.

Comment: If you start a counter at zero, then increment it by one every time you get a heads, but reset to zero every time you get a tails, then you just have to check if the counter's value is at 6, and then display the "you are very lucky" message. The whole line with `rand == 1 and rand == 1` makes no sense; to me it looks like [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @RandomDavis -- In fairness, many beginners assume that referring to a variable again will redo whatever process created the variable.  That's what he's done here.  Incorrect, but not unnatural.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "And I was wondering if anyone can help me do that." Well, *what help is needed*? This is [not yet a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/) - please read [ask]. What don't you understand about the task? In your own words, what do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? Where do you get stuck when you try to write the code for it?

Answer (score 1):

An if statement like this should work:

```py
if heards_count == 6:
     print('You are very lucky!')
```

`heards_count` can only equal 6 if you pass in six to the function headsOrTails(). Get rid of the line

```py
if rand == 1 and rand == 1 and rand == 1 and rand == 1:
```

`rand` will be reset on each iteration of the loop so it does not check if rand has been equal to 1 four times. Hope this helps!

Comment: What you suggest will show that message as soon as he gets 6 heads.  It does NOT detect 6 heads IN A ROW.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.  I would use the heads_count and the tails_count as a heads/tails in a row count.  If you get a heads, reset the tails count.  If you get a tails, reset the heads count.

```
import random


def headsOrTails():
    number_of_flips = int(input("How many times do you want to flip the coin: "))
    heads_count = 0
    tails_count = 0
    for i in range(number_of_flips):
        rand = random.randint(1, 2)
        if rand == 1:
            tails_count = 0
            heads_count += 1
            print(f"It is Heads.\n Heads in a row {heads_count}")
        elif rand == 2:
            heads_count = 0
            tails_count += 1
            print(f"It is Tails.\n Tails in a row {tails_count}")

        if heads_count == 6 or tails_count == 6:
            print("You are very lucky")


headsOrTails()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def headsOrTails(n):
    heads_count = 0
    tails_count = 0
    heads_inarow = 0
    tails_inarow = 0
    for i in range(n):
        rand = random.randint(1, 2)
        if rand == 1:
            tails_inarow = 0
            heads_inarow += 1
            heads_count += 1
            print(f"It is Heads.\n Heads in a row {heads_inarow}")
        elif rand == 2:
            heads_inarow = 0
            tails_inarow += 1
            tails_count += 1
            print(f"It is Tails.\n Tails in a row {tails_inarow}")

        if heads_inarow == 6 or tails_inarow == 6:
            print("You are very lucky")
    print(heards_count)
    print(tails_count)

number_of_flips = int(input("How many times do you want to flip the coin: "))
headsOrTails(number_of_flips)
```